# Can somebody Explain This Actionscript Line of Code to me?

Tags: actionscript, flash

var loc3:*=Math.min(Math.max(arg2 / arg1.things, 0), 1);

If somebody could breakdown what this line of code is doing, i'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rewrite it in the following sequence of steps:

```
VALUE1 = arg2 / arg1.things      // STEP 1   divide arg2 by arg1.things
VALUE2 = Math.max(VALUE1, 0)     // STEP 2   if the value of the division at step 1
                                            is less then 0, set the value to 0
VALUE3 = Math.min(VALUE2, 1)     // STEP 3   if the value is greater than 1
                                            set the value to 1
VALUE4 = loc3 * VALUE3           // STEP 4   multiply the value by the current value 
                                             stored in loc3
var loc3 = VALUE4;               // STEP 5   and set the final value back to loc3
```

So, to summarize, what that line of code does is it divides the value of `arg2` by the values stored in `arg1.things` and it caps the result in the closed interval `[0,1]` and then it multiplies the value stored in `loc3` by the capped, computed result of the division. The final result is stored back in the `loc3` variable.

Comment: But if the computed result is between 0 and 1, it uses that result right?

Comment: Yup, if the computed result is greater than 0 and less than 1 it will use that, otherwise either 0 or 1 whichever is "closer"..